# How can I hide the lines Android Studio is showing at line breaks?

Tags: android, android-studio, editor

Android Studio is showing me some lines in the code editor where I added a line break. It looks like some indentation indicator, see attached screenshot.

[screenshot: the horizontal part of the lines is what I want to eliminate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWrYl.png)

I tried to configure a lot of the editor and style and colour option for more than an hour now, but I don't get rid of these lines.

It's absolutely disturbing me, but I can't get it away. Does anybody have a hint for me?

Answer (score 0):

Check the preferences or settings

Editor -> Appearance -> Show right margin

Most recent versions used:

Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show right margin

or

Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show hard wrap guide

Comment: Thanks Josef for your help.
Unfortunately it's not what I meant, the settings just show/hide the vertical line on the right side of the code.

I wanted to get rid of the lines that are shown in the image above in the original post (unfortunately I cannot embed images as I do not have 10 reputations... :-(

Comment: you can upload the image somewhere like google drive and share the link

Comment: Yes, i did see the link in my original post, or here again:https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWrYl.png